Should All Variables Have Adjusted P-Values in Multiple Hypothesis Testing or Just Hypotheses-Relevant Variables?
I'm currently working on a project involving multiple hypothesis testing. I understand the importance of adjusting p-values to control for Type I errors, but I'm unsure whether I should adjust the p-values for all variables or just the ones relevant to the hypotheses being tested.
I have 10 outcome (dependent) variables, a treatment variable (dummy variable: Treatment group vs. control group), and 7 socio-demographic variables and am using Romano-Wolf MHT corrections.
Most papers I have come across adjust the p-value for all independent variables (e.g. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.joep.2024.102707), but surely this drastically increases the probability of type II error.
Could someone explain the best practice for this scenario? Should I focus on adjusting p-values for all variables in my dataset, or is it sufficient to adjust only for the variables directly related to my hypotheses?
Any guidance or references to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
A similar question has been asked here: Adjust p-value of the all output or just the variable of interest?, but it does not fully address my specific context and concerns.

If a p-value is not relevant, then there was no need to compute it in the first place.  Why, then, would you adjust for something that you haven't even computed?  (One is reminded of the proverbial question about whether falling trees make any sound when one is not around to hear them...)

The p-values are often computed even if they are not the primary focus (e.g. for control variables),. I am just very surprised why most papers I come across adjust all p-values rather than just those of primary interest.

I don't see any point in calculating p-values for control variables. Software spits out the p-values automatically, but I wouldn't report them and I think it's safe to ignore them entirely. I would therefore not adjust for them.
